# wp_category_checklist doesn't accept selected categories parameter

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I can't figure out why wp_category_checklist doesn't accept selected categories parameter when i pull data out of the database.

I have custom table in databse and in that table one of the fields is called

```
post_category
```

In this field i have comma separated list of categories id's and this list is just like this i copied numbers below directly from my table.

```
136, 8, 46, 9
```

The problem is that i want to use wp_category_checklist on my plugin page and to select those categories that are with id's from database field but function for some reason doesn't accept that parameter when it's pulled from database.

So to get my field values from database i use this

```
$item['post_category'];
```

And this returns categories id's, if i echo or print_r it i would get this

```
$cats = $item['post_category'];
echo $cats;
print_r($cats);

output on both is 136, 8, 46, 9
```

So by this results and by reading wp_category_checklist codex page i guess if  i use this

```
wp_category_checklist(0, 0, $cats);
```

I will get categories that match id's with numbers from my field checked

But no it's not working, any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = explode(",",$cats);
wp_category_checklist(0, 0, $arr);
```

Third parameter is array.

Comment: What if i use it like this $cats = array($item['post_category']; wouldn't that make it an array? i tried like this also but no luck

Comment: Anyway your code works, but why do i need to explode does the parameter from the table is returned as string? so even if i wrap it into array($cats) it still wont work? can you explain if it's not a problem?

Comment: It considers the complete string as first/only element in array. How will php know that you have provided comma separated integers?

Comment: I thought if i wrap it in array($cats) it will divide it on every comma.